# If 1D and 2D array always have equivalent content will time complexity differ?

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, time-complexity

If, for example, I have a set of numbers and I populate a copy in a 1d array and a copy in a 2d array. So essentially I have, and will always have an equivalent amount of elements in each array.  In this case does the time complexity actually differ, holding in mind that the number of elements will will be always equivalent?

Answer (score 1):

No, the time complexity of the same algorithm operating on both types of inputs will be the same. Intuitively, the time complexity of an algorithm will not change just because the input data is arranged in a different way.

That being said, apparently the notion of *input size* depends a bit on the context, which can be puzzling. When discussing *sorting* algorithms, the input consists of `n` elements, which means that a time complexity of e.g. `O(n)` (which however is impossible for comparison-based sorting) would be termed *linear*. In contrast, when discussing algorithms for *matrix multiplication*, the input is usually imagined as an `n*n` matrix - which has not `n`, but `n^2` elements. In this case, an algorithm of complexity of `O(n*n)` (which however is unlikely again) would again be termed *linear*, although the expression describing it is actually a square term.

To put it all in a nutshell, the time complexity refers to the actual *input size*, not some technical parameter which might be different from it.